# "react-native" is not recognized in cmd

Tags: react-native, cmd

I wanna install react-native-cli so I do 
`C:\Users\fghjz_o4dbsvs\Documents\Main App\Programs\My Practices\React\ReactApp\laravel_react2>npm install -g react-native-cli` 
and cmd show me

```
C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\npm\react-native -> C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js
+ react-native-cli@2.0.1
updated 1 package in 6.666s
```

↑　I have no idea what happen. please tell me advice.

And next I do

```
react-native --version
```

but

```
'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Answer (score 0):

try `npx react-native`.

Please check this https://github.com/react-native-community/cli#creating-a-new-react-native-project more details.